# Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, array-merge

I was solving the leetcode question Merge Sorted Array and I am getting runtime error while running the following code on leetcode

> Given two sorted integer arrays nums1 and nums2, merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array.
> The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively. You may assume that nums1 has a size equal to m + n such that it has enough space to hold additional elements from nums2.

Example 1:
Input: nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3
Output: [1,2,2,3,5,6]

Example 2:
Input: nums1 = [1], m = 1, nums2 = [], n = 0
Output: [1]

**my code :**

```
class Solution {
public:
void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = m-1;
    
    while(i<=k && j<m) {
        if(nums1[i] < nums2[j]) {
            i++;
        }
        else {
            swap(nums2[j++], nums1[k--]);
        }
    }
    sort(begin(nums1), begin(nums1) + m );
    sort(begin(nums2), end(nums2));
    
    k = m + 1;
    for(int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        nums1[k] = nums2[l];
        k++;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Think about `j < m`, which vector `j` indexes, and which vector's size is `m`.

Comment: To whoever said just to use a debugger, seconded.

Comment: @underscore_d It was me, but I removed my comment and made it into an answer instead. I lost the debugger suggestion in the process :-) I've added it to  the answer now.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you! you are right it should be `j < n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
k = m + 1;
```

Makes it skip the slot at `k[m]` and also makes the `for` loop access `nums1` out of bounds since `k` will reach `6` and `nums1[6]` is out of bounds.

Make it:

```
k = m;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rx79n7T1j)

Note: Errors of this kind are easy to find if you use a debugger or even by adding print outs in your code so you can see the values of the index variables.

Comment: @doggone_boy Not with the data you showed in the question (check out the demo). You may have additional bugs, like making assuptions about the vector sizes etc. The bug in the question should be solved by this change though.

Comment: Yes I figured out the second one. Thank you! @TedLyngmo